# Timestampable does not work with ORM and PostgreSQL database

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, stofdoctrineextensions

I added support for `Timestampable` in my entity as follow: `use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;`. I have updated my DB by running `doctrine:schema:update --force` but any time I try to insert a new record I get this message:

> SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "createdat" violates not-null constraint

Why? I'm using latest Symfony 2.5.3 and PostgreSQL 9.2.9. This is the complete error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO usuarios_externos.usuarios (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, locked, expired, expires_at, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, 
>   roles, credentials_expired, credentials_expire_at, id, persona, correo_alternativo, telefono, telefono_movil, fax, pagina_web, direccion, deletedAt, createdAt, updatedAt, pais_id, estado_id, municipio_id, ciudad_id, parroquia_id) VALUES (?, 
>   ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["reynier", "reynier", "reynierpm@gmail.com", "reynierpm@gmail.com", "false", "hhm95if1uog88koggos48csk48k0w80", 
>   "sVzbTOHgZzhU92zPHBFsVG3GqV+DO5xvXxvNdC5/GVJ/Hnvlm8rBsNDsIgPKYXdZ4NcnONqXnrOB6UR+lAluAw==", null, "false", "false", null, null, null, "a:0:{}", "false", null, 3, "true", "reynierpm1@gmail.com", "021245678999", "", "", "", "sadasdasd", 
>   null, null, null, 23, 1, 1, 1, 22]

Any advice?

**Added entity**

```
<?php

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuarios_externos.usuarios", schema="usuarios_externos")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Usuario extends BaseUser
{

    ....

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updated
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $updated;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

    ....

    public function getCreated()
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function getUpdated()
    {
        return $this->updated;
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;
    }

    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you added the timestampable annotation to the created at property?

Comment: @ThomasK yes I added the `Timestampable` annotation but I did some research and I though PostgreSQL handle timestamp different than MySQL as said [here](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2008/03/mysql-versus-postgresql-adding-a-last-modified-column-to-a-table.html) or [here](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2006/aug/04/automatically-updating-a-timestamp-column-in-postgresql/) even if I check the columns at DB they have not default values in MySQL they have

Comment: Just to be sure, can you post code for the createdAt property with annotations?

Comment: @ThomasK done already added to main post

Comment: @ReynierPM, Have you added gedmo listener into services.yml? Example: https://gist.github.com/korotovsky/ebb1387e9a3e80a30a9c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should enable timestampable in your config:

```
stof_doctrine_extensions:
    orm:
        default:
            timestampable: true
```

Comment: That was the error but now I'm getting this another error `Unable to find timestampable [created] as mapped property in entity - Sencamer\UsuarioBundle\Entity\Usuario` what I miss? the setter?

Comment: @ReynierPM I've got the same error. Do you find a solution?