# How is timestampable used?

Tags: php

I was taking a test and saw this function:

```
Class Object{
    use Timestampable;
}
$object= new Object();
$object->setCreatedAt(new DateTime());
```

I believe it was a trick question, because I don't find "timestampable" in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=timestampable&scope=quickref).

I have seen references to it on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433550/timestampable-does-not-work-with-orm-and-postgresql-database), which got me confused to if it actually can be used.  I know of timestamp in the MySQL database, but does this actually exist or have a use in PHP?

Comment: It's part of a library, it's called Gedmo which then again is an extension of doctrine. It's not in the standard PHP, therefor also not documented.

Comment: to be more specific - it's part of some third-party library

Comment: In the case that you want to work with dates and timestamps and what not, use the `DateTime` class. It supports pretty much anything you'd like with it.

Comment: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/HEAD//doc/timestampable.md This really helped me find documentation.:)  I added a link for more info in case someone else has this question.

Answer (score 2):

Timestampable is a so-called [**trait**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) and is meant to help reuse code.

Let's say you have a bunch of entities and all of them have some common functionality, e.g. they all need `$createdAt` and `$updatedAt` fields. You could achieve this functionality by creating a common base class for all entities, but that wouldn't be great from architecture standpoint.

Instead you could create a trait:

```php
trait Timestampable
{
    protected DateTime $createdAt;
    protected DateTime $updatedAt;   
    ...
}
```

And then use it like so:

```php
class User
{
    use Timestampable;
}
```

Now `User` objects will have `$createdAt` field and any other fields or methods that are defined in the trait, just like they would be defined inside the `User` class. This way you don't need to repeat the same code in all of your classes.

Timestampable is one of more common traits, but obviously traits aren't limited to that. [Here's an example of a more complete Timestapable trait](https://gist.github.com/merk/8907106).

*I know this is a 4 year old question, but it was the top result on google, so thought it may be helpful for others.*

Answer (score 1):

The question on the test is not about a `Timestampable` function, that is just the example. The question is designed to your knowledge of abstract classes, interfaces and traits.